# How to insert newline ('\n') in terminal input with keyboard properly?

Tags: c, terminal, getchar

Consider the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
    return 0;
}
```

and consider the following as the desired input:

```
LINE1

LINE2
```

If I start typing the input into the terminal window, once I hit the enter/return key the input so far is printed to the screen; which I wouldn't like to happen. (it seems like the terminal sends everything typed to the program once the enter/return key is pressed)

I would like to be able to type all the lines into the terminal and then see the output all in one place, instead of having the output be printed once I hit enter at the end of every line.

Is there a way to insert newlines without having the input sent to the application?

Comment: How is the program supposed to determine that the input is done?

Comment: Save the input into a string. Print the whole string when the loop is done.

Comment: Nope, there is no terminal mode that buffers multiple lines. But your program can buffer as many lines as it wants to. In other words, instead of calling `putchar`, your program should store the characters in an array until you're ready to print them.

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't know, maybe once I am finished I can press enter/return? I'm just trying to insert \n without hitting enter.

Comment: And you might as well use `fgets()` to read a whole line at a time, instead of `getchar()`.

Comment: There's no way to insert `\n` without pressing Enter -- that's the key that sends `\n`.

Comment: To signal EOF, press Ctl-d on an empty line on Unix, Ctl-z on Windows.

Comment: @Barmar well that's one way, another is to type my input into a text editor and then copy and paste that into the terminal. If I copy and paste it has the desired effect.

Comment: @Titan No it doesn't, you just can't see that it's printing each line as it's read.

Comment: You can put the text in a file and redirect the program's input: `./program < filename`

Comment: @Barmar Oh that's interesting, so the behavior is the same when I copy it.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I'm aware of redirecting the input as well, I was just wondering why it works when I copy the input into terminal, which you answered earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220158/discussion-between-titan-and-barmar).

Comment: If you need direct access to the terminal IO, you might want to consider using the non-standard curses package: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library), or if you're on Windows the conio package: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most systems use input buffering, i.e. the input is buffered up and will not be send to the application until the input is a newline.

AFAIK there is no way to prevent the system from sending the buffered data to the application when the input is a newline.

Therefor you need to implement your own buffer system on top of the systems buffer system.

Something like:

```
int main() {
    int c;
    size_t capacity = 64;
    size_t write_index = 0;
    char *buffer = malloc(capacity);
    assert(buffer != NULL);

    // Buffer input
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (write_index == capacity)
        {
            // Increase buffer
            capacity = 2 * capacity;
            char *tmp = realloc(buffer, capacity);
            assert(tmp != NULL);
            buffer = tmp;
        }
        buffer[write_index] = c;
        ++write_index;
    }

    // Process input
    for (size_t i = 0; i < write_index; ++i)
    {
        putchar(buffer[i]);
    }

    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Then all input will be buffered until you input EOF (i.e. ctrl-d or ctrl-z) and you do the processing afterwards.

Comment: Would `fwrite(buffer,1,write_index,stdout)` be preferable to the `putchar` loop?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to be able to type all the lines into the terminal and
> then see the output all in one place, instead of having the output be
> printed once I hit enter at the end of every line

I am not sure I understand what you want to do. The short answer is yes, you can. But the behavior you want is not clear to me, so at least to me is hard to say how you can do what you want

You can treat the char `c` inside the loop, you can disable ECHO on read, and write only when you want, you can manage the console processing as described in [here if you are using Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions)

Under Unix and derivatives the model is different, since Linux/Unix/Mac has no console. You use `ioctl()` and manipulate `VMIN` and `VTIME` parameters

What platform are you using?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I originally thought it might be possible to write '\n' into terminal input without causing the input buffer being sent over to the program (I thought maybe the Enter/Return key is the one signaling terminal to send the input over to the program). But as it turns out, '\n' itself is the one causing this to happen. I'm using Mac OS btw.

Comment: I believe you can use the Unix `ioctl()` and set VTIME and VMIN to 0, disable echo on input and treat each char inside the loop

Comment: Does that put the terminal into raw mode?

Comment: it depends on the parameters of the call. But in short yes

Comment: anyway I am still not sure about what you are trying to achieve. I am assuming `putchar(c)` is a placeholder for something you choose not to post. `getchar()` in itself in normal mode includes displaying the character read, an implicit `putchar(c)`. Due to the way `stdout` works, like a tty terminal from the 70's, when you press `enter` the line buffer  is flushed. If you just write `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){}` the output will be as you described...

Comment: Honestly I asked it out of curiosity, nothing special in mind for now. I'm used to copying my input from a text editor and dropping it into terminal because in that case the output of the program starts from the end of the pasted text, which I apparently can't achieve by directly typing it into terminal.